# Emacs handle when file renamed externally

Tags: buffers, files

**How can I configure Emacs to update a buffer's file association when the file is renamed externally?**

In Textmate, I can open a file "foo.txt", use a different program to rename the file to "bar.txt", and Textmate automatically notices that the file was renamed. The new filename is displayed in the Textmate's window title, and editing and saving the file writes the changes to "bar.txt".

In Emacs, if I open a file "foo.txt" then use a different program to rename the file to "bar.txt", Emacs' buffer is still associated with "foo.txt". Editing and saving the file writes the file back to "foo.txt", but I would like it to write the file to "bar.txt" (I would also like the buffer name to change to "bar.txt", and for `revert-buffer` to read the file from "bar.txt").

Comment: Perhaps you can file a feature request against `auto-revert-mode`.

Comment: This separation of buffers from filenames on disk is an essential part of emacs flexibility, a flexibility that comes with great benefit when editing remote files. That is why the emacs tutorial spends a lot of time upfront describing the difference between buffers and files. However if you want a custom behavior, look into file notification extensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to implement this yourself, then I imagine you need to utilise the Notifications on File Changes functionality (provided that one of the requisite libraries is supported on your OS).

<kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(elisp) File Notifications` <kbd>RET</kbd>

Comment: IIUC, Textmate runs on OS X. There is no file notification library for Emacs available these days. Integration of kqueue has been discussed, but nobody has implemented yet.

Comment: @MichaelAlbinus what about [`inotify`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify)?  I believe `magit-filenotify` uses something based on that.

Comment: Inotify support is integrated in Emacs, so there's no problem on GNU/Linux systems. But I suppose somebody, who wants Textmate features, runs her Emacs instance on OS X.

Comment: Ah, indeed! This is on OS X.

Comment: @MichaelAlbinus you say "there is no problem", but currently it is not implented, right ?

Comment: Well, perfect timing! Yesterday I've merged some local work into the Emacs development version, which provides kqueue support on *BSD and OS X. File notification shall work now also on OS X!